# Should we use api gateway(such as zuul) between microservices?

Tags: microservices, netflix-zuul, api-gateway

There is no doubt that API gateway should be the edge server to outside world.
We are wondering that should we use API gateway in the communications between the microservices?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can definitely use API gateway lets say for that matter (netflix -zuul) for inter-service calls, only thing of concern for you would be,

what happens when you start versioning your services, assuming you'll be using eureka as a naming server from which zuul gateway will fetch all registered services, but now in your case zuul will get two instances of your service (version previous and verison next) and ribbon will load balance the requests between the two, this point is already thoughtfully covered in

[How to route in between microservices using Spring Cloud & Netflix OSS](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31313170/7756558)

Basically if you are familiar with BlueGreen Deployment model, implementing that would be a problem, surely there are proper workarounds for that as in defining/registering  some metadata along with your previous and latest versions which would later be picked by ribbon client to route accordingly